# Vcard file can get a data from a link?

Tags: php, vcf-vcard

Question
**example** 
In normaly  i get Vcard file  from my directory like a "vcard2.vcf"
Vcard file  can get from  a link  like a  "www.egg/vcard3.vcf." ?

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch from url as well:

file_get_contents('http://url-to-your-vcard-file.vcf')

Comment: Hi Marius  Can you give me example link  .vcf  file

Comment: According to your question, you should be able to know where your files are. Just put them in a web-accessible folder (like you do with images and  css and js) and you'll be able to access them. For instance, create a folder "vcards" in the web root folder and you'll be able to access vcf files with http://www.yoursitename.com/vcards/card-name.vcf